# How do I determine cutline when distribution is exponential-like?

Tags: data-analysis, exponential-distribution, eda

I am currently working on e-commerce customer data analysis.

I plotted customer-click distribution and got the image below.

[image]

X = number of clicks / Y = number of customers

It seems like exponential-distribution to me..(Not exactly, but similar)

I want to use customer data with a certain amount of clicks for analysis, but I have no idea how to get right cut-line.

How do I determine what kind of distribution exactly it is, and where to cut off?

Please help me..

Comment: Well, the distribution is right skewed from Data Science / Statistical point of view. Also please explain, what do you exactly mean by "cutline" or "cut-off" in your question ?

Comment: For example if cutline is 3, I would discard data that is X < 3 and only use data X>=3 for analysis.

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using to plot this graph ? Based on that I can suggest how to implement cut off line